# no power after resseting cmos?

Tags: motherboard, power, reset, cmos

My computer wouldn't let my usb keyboard work on boot and i could not access BIOS. So, i did what i usually do and remove the battery from the mobo and put it back again.At first, it would turn on but wouldn't let my keyboard work so i could not get into the BIOS setup or go past the initial boot with common settings. I turned it off and decided to try again. But now, it does not even get power. I checked my cords, removed them and put them back again. I even removed the battery and put it back again. But no luck.

What should i do?

Comment: If the CMOS battery is more than about three years old, it is worth trying a new one.